# How to transfer int variable addresses in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I want to transfer `int` memory from program to program:

This is how i get the `int` memory allocation, and i want to print it:

```
ioresult main (char *params) {
  int year=0, month=0, day=0, hour=0 ,min=0, i=0;
  char * token;
  char *p = params;

  printf("DateMethod: %s\n",params);
  token = strtok(params, " ");

   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      if(i == 0) {
        year = (void *)(strtol(token, NULL, 0));
      } else if(i == 1) {
        month = (void *)(strtol(token, NULL, 0));
      } else if(i == 2) {
        day = (void *)(strtol(token, NULL, 0));
      } else if(i == 3) {
        hour = (void *)(strtol(token, NULL, 0));
      } else if(i == 4) {
        min = (void *)(strtol(token, NULL, 0));
      }

      token = strtok(NULL, " ");

      i++;
   }

  printf("Method Date: %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d\n", year, month, day, hour, min);

  return S_OK;
}
```

The `params` print show me:

```
DateMethod: 0x904 0x905 0x906 0x907 0x908
```

But in the other `printf` i get this:

```
Method Date: 2309-2310-2311 2312:00
```

And this is not the values inside the int. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: If your input string has hexadecimal data as `0x904`, then `strtol` can't  parse that.

Comment: the values below are (one off) hex values converted to decimal. Try with %02x format

Comment: That's some really strange code, but 0x905 is 2309 and so on...

Comment: 0x904 is 2308 more precisely.

Comment: How are you calling this code?  What is your input and expected output?

Comment: why are you converting the values to `(void *)` ?

Comment: The prototype of `main` is `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, casting the result of strtol to `(void*)` is weird, assigning the result of the cast to an `int` is even weirder (and should not compile).

Comment: @AProgrammer `(and should not compile)` it will compile of course. In C implicit pointers to another types are allowed but are UBs.

Comment: "I want to transfer int memory from program to program" Eh? What does this have to do with this code? I don't understand what you are doing. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Transfer integers through IPC?

Comment: @P__J__, source? For what it's worth, gcc with -pedantic-errors fails, without pass.

Comment: @AProgrammer -pedantic-errors it is not standard C feature. -Werror  also. So do not use some command line options when you say something about the standart. Modern compilers emit warnings on most common UBs. You can tell the compiler to treat them as errors. Then any program with warnings (legal from the standard point of view) will not compile

Comment: The code doesn't correspond to the question, and the claimed output doesn't correspond to the code.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `strtol` can pass "0x" in both base 0 and 16

Comment: This question is unclear. In the title and text the problem is described as "transfer int variable address" but the code seems to pass a string to extract number from hex representation. On top of that the code seems to be about date/time values. Please clarify

Comment: @P__J__, I checked before making the affirmation -- I was concerned that it was another case where C is laxer than C++.  I was unable to find the place which allow such a conversion (although I found the place which allow `0` and the place which make it implementation defined -- and not UB -- to cast from int to a pointer).  It would not be the first time I miss something in a standard.  Could you give me your source that it is allowed but UB?

Comment: @AProgrammer [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6):  "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type."

Comment: @AProgrammer It is allowed in the C++ as well. Otherwise, no hardware memory mapped registers programming. https://godbolt.org/z/SEa6t-  I am not going to search the standard for ya

Comment: @P__J__, in your godbolt, you have a cast.  That is working. 6.3.2.3/6 describes what happens if you cast.  I'd have expected the case handled in [6.5.16.1/1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1).

Comment: @AProgrammer in C casts are only to avoid warnings. C++ requires explicit casts

Answer (score -2):

You program does not make too much sense but here you have version printing what you want, without bizarre casts https://godbolt.org/z/TKwxzR

You cant pass the addresses of the local variables as those variables only exists when the function is executed. They are deleted on the function return. When the function will be called again the addresses of the auto variables can be different.